# RewriteBase rule for redirecting to the same directory does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dash-dev/dist
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /dash-dev/dist [L]
```

This works and if I follow the path http://127.0.0.1/dash-dev/dist/asdas/asd then it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1/dash-dev/dist/
But I have a registration on the site and when I go along the path http://127.0.0.1/ajax/signup then it throws me to http://127.0.0.1/dash-dev/dist/ which should not be.
Why it happens?
My apache: 2.4.38 (Debian)

Comment: Well probably because `ajax/signup` does not actually physically exist in the file system - which is what your RewriteConds are checking for. If it does not exist as a file, or a folder, or a symbolic link - then the following rule will rewrite it.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

Comment: It is not there because I am redirecting